# System read-only after upgrading Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, server, 16.04, upgrade

Today I upgraded my Ubuntu Server from 14.04 to 16.04 with `sudo do-release-upgrade`, which went smoothly until it rebooted and I logged in. Where I am met with the following message:

```
Unable to setup logging. [Error 30] Read only file system:
'var/log/landspace/sysinfo.log' 

run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo exited with return code 1

/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 39: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrader-available: Read-only file system

/usr/lib/update-notierfier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /usr/liv/update-notifier-fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system

-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
```

So I have figured that the system is read-only and this a preventive measure if there is some sort of error/corruption of the file system or the disk?

So my questions is two folded:

1. What did exactly happen?
2. How do I fix it?

Don't know if this is relevant, but the OS is running of a USB-pen while there are 6 drives in Raid 5.

Thanks in advance!

Obviously I could just reinstall the OS and setup everything again, which would only take me a couple of hours, but I really want to learn and understand it instead :)

**Edit 1**

dmesg log added: http://pastebin.com/0bP8T4hH

**Edit 2**

`/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/dev/md0        /mnt/rdisk      ext4    user    0       0
```

Comment: `dmesg` output would help. But out of top of my head, I'd guess that usb stick started producing IO errors, forcing OS to remount the file system. Btw, I'm not sure if you did it, but given the system is on a stick, moving whole `/var/log/` directory to a tmpfs would both prolong life of the stick, and make boot much faster. `noatime` mount option would help too.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I posted a pastebin link of my dmesg log into the original question. No I haven't moved `/var/log/`to a tmpfs, but I may look into that when I get everything up and running again.

Comment: Well, I can't tell for sure, but seems your problem starts at 1936 line, which looks like a disk failing.

Comment: That disk have been failing for some time, and is currently set as a spare disk in my raid until I replace it. Haven't been a problem before the upgrade, and since the OS is installed on a USB I don't think that is the problem.

I've tried to remount / with  `mount -o -remount,rw /`, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm, what does say `mount | grep " / "`?

Comment: `/dev/sdg1 on / type ext4 (ro,relative,data=ordered)`

Comment: What does say `grep -E "\s/\s" /etc/fstab` ?

Comment: `# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation`

Comment: Hmm, that's already interesting. Could you, please, add to the question the `/etc/fstab` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason your `/etc/fstab` doesn't even mention mount point of the root of directories. Given that you actually have system on `/dev/sdg1`, modify the file as follows:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/dev/md0        /mnt/rdisk      ext4    user    0       0
/dev/sdg1       /               ext4            rw,noatime,data=ordered 0 1
```

Reboot to test if it works, but actually I wouldn't recommend to use `/dev/sdg1` directly in the file, because device name could change. You're better off to use UUID of the filesystem. To find it execute `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdg1`. Then replace `/dev/sdg1` with `UUID=The-Number-You-Just-Got` in the `/etc/fstab`.