# Ubuntu boots to “Read Only Filesystem” after Upgrading from 16.04 > 16.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, kubuntu

After upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 I am running into some trouble.

My situation is I have 2 harddrives and several partitions on each.

drive0

- Kubuntu 16.10
- Windows7

drive1

- Kubuntu 16.04

The Kubuntu 16.10 on drive0 boots into read-only file system.
Hard to make a screen-shot but it briefly shows me the Kubuntu splash screen and then shows me a login.

After some googling I found out that if I remount like so

- `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/dev/sda3' /`

And then hit `startx` ... it will boot normally.

So at the moment this is how I boot untill someone here can give the solution. All help very much appreciated.

I already tried this: [Ubuntu boots to "Read Only Filesystem" after Upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640639/ubuntu-boots-to-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrading)

I read this: [Ubuntu boots in read-only filesystem after upgrade!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201088/ubuntu-boots-in-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrade)

I would like to see if I can fix... before I think about hardware failure.

I checked my hard-drives now and all drives and partitions are fine.Clean bill of SMART health.

Comment: nobody a clue? Can't imagine that. I can give you more info but I need to know what. Any help appreciated.    tnx in advance

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/814687

Comment: hi tnx, It indeed looks like something that might help me. However my /etc/fstab is a bit more complicated.  I will have a try.